One neutral wire, carrying electricity in both directions?

This is a simple circuit with battery, also think it as AC source.
One neutral wire in the middle.
Two power source, two hot wires.
Will it carry electricity in both directions at the same time?
Will be it a problem?
I've IPS connection in my home.
I also want to add solar connection with the IPS. Then I'll remove the main source to the IPS. It'll supply electricity with solar energy to the IPS connected (has hot wire) devices.
All the appliances share one neutral line throughout the house.
Will it be a problem?

By what criteria are you asking "will it be a problem"?  This is not how high voltage home wiring is installed.  So tell us, in the question, why you want to do it this way, what are the objectives, how will you go about cabling it, what is wrong with a more traditional approach?   If we judge this by normal criteria of wiring for a home, yes it will be many problems but that doesn't really make sense.

What's an IPS, please?

Currents from two separate loads connected to two separate hots flowing in opposite directions in a wire are subracted to give the current actually flowing in the wire. There is even a type of house circuit called a multiwire branch circuit which takes advantage of this to share a neutral in which currents from two separate breakers (but 180 deg out of phase) are flowing in opposite directions in the neutral. The curent in the neutral can be zero, yet the current in the two hots may be well above zero. In your case the current flowing through the joining segment in heavy line could be about 0.

@jay613  4 years ago, when electrician told me where to put IPS (Instant power supply, that's I found online, Backup power), I told to put a place, and the main circuit board is on other side of the room. In this case, I assume there is some connections like this I put on the picture.I bought a solar inverter. When there is no electricity in main line, only the IPS is supplying power, there is no overlap. But when I'll use solar, aside from main line, there might be overlap. Even I don't know how much. And there are only 5 ceiling fans, ~10 LED on the IPS line.

@JimStewart Yes I understand what you picture about. It might be zero overall if both side have same load. Thanks!

There are ways to connect solar inverters to your home power wiring.  You should buy the correct equipment and either learn how to do it or get someone who knows how.   Your diagram and your ideas for "sharing neutrals" are not correct.  Start by googling "How to connect a solar inverter to your home".   Watch some videos.  Read.

Okay, I'll follow proper guide when I'll install. Currently it's running as just backup power system.

To improve that diagram, connect the red wire from the left-hand battery to the left-hand load, and the red wire from the right-hand battery to the right-hand load. That eliminates one crossover, and shortens those wandering red lines. Then reverse the right-hand battery. No more crisscrossing, and it's much clearer what's going on.

Why did you draw this so Picasso? (also one of your batteries is aiming the wrong way).  But I see what you're going for.  Try this

This is literally the author-created thumbnail of this here video. He's talking about lost neutrals, but you can see how it all works.

This is a simple circuit with battery, also think it as AC source.

That's fine by the way. The metaphor translates.

Thank you very much!!!
